# Why my WCF service doesn't expose metadata?

Tags: wcf, metadata

I'm fighting with a WCF service which doesn' want to expose metadata. The configuration file, according to a lot of posts around internet, seems to be OK:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="Mia.Configurazione" name="Mio.UserService">
        <endpoint address="JSON" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MioWS.IUserService" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="JSONEndpointBehavior" bindingConfiguration="" name="RESTEP">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MioWS.IUserService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
```

When I try to type this url:

```
http://localhost:55555/api/UserService.svc/$metadata
```

the server replies with an HTTP error 400 (Bad Request). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add base address for service and try your url, ending with . . ./mex instead of /$metadata

Comment: The server replies always "Bad request"

Comment: @PierpaoloIlConteParis - did you fix this problem?